# Jenkins run a script in background

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, background-process

How can I trigger a script say A (in python) using Jenkins such that a shell script triggered internally from script A keeps running in background even after Jenkins build is done.

Right now, what I observe is that as soon as Jenkins job ends, it kills the background shell script too.
However, running the python script manually on the terminal is fine.

Is there a way that I can skip killing that background shell script from Jenkins?

Comment: what about this `nohup python my_scipt.py &`

Comment: any other way? I lose access to logs and cant check if it fails at any step

Comment: you can capture logs to file nohup python_script.py > myprogram.out 2> myprogram.err

Comment: or more suitable way `nohup python_script.py >  ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText 2>  ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText`

Comment: But problem is jenkins build will always pass

Comment: you are expecting job status from python or bash script?

Comment: from python script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching for the solution, I came across this link "Spawning process from build"

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build

Adding below command to build step helped:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup shell_script_to_run.sh &
```